# How to copy files from one directory to another by dates?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, file-transfer, file-management

I want to copy files from one folder to another. I go to the command prompt to copy files from one folder to another. I want to copy files based on dates.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please have a look at robocopy.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Dojingle ISIS - From command prompt type in `FOR /?` and press enter. Look for section as you press to get to each new screen until you see the substitution variables and the one shown as `%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file` and then test in a `FOR` loop doing `ECHO` commands to see how it works, etc. Check out `FORFILES /?` with an enter too. You can do some commands there based on file date modified attributes as well. There are to good starting points so read, test, and then [edit] your question with what you need help with and show what you tried that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the **forfiles** command.  This command will select files based on a criteria, such as a *date* and then allow you to perform a command on them like *move, copy, delete*, etc...

This site will be your best friend for windows commands (cmd.exe) http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Comment: Who dat der be creeping?